# Múltiplo retorno em clausula IN e CASE usando Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho uma situação, usando uma procedure Oracle-SQL, onde dependendo do valor informado de uma variável (SIM/NÃO), o valor que está sendo utilizado na query irá mudar. Tentei conforme abaixo mas retorna o erro:

**ORA-00932: tipos de dados inconsistentes: esperava CHAR obteve SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST**

Trecho do SQL que tentei montar (no lugar do primeiro 'S' vai a variável) da procedure.

```
AND  mc.segment3             in (CASE WHEN 'S' = 'S' THEN
                                         sys.odcivarchar2list('060','071')
                                      ELSE sys.odcivarchar2list('059')
                                 END)
```

Comment: Tentou colocar isso num sub-select?

Comment: @BrunoWarmling estou tentando pensar em um subselect agora

Comment: ( (VS = 'S' AND mc.segment3 IN ('060','071')
  OR  
  (VS <> 'S' AND mc.segment3 IN ('059') )

Comment: @Motta, nao acredito que em uma linha tu resolveu isso...pqp. Posta ai como resposta, valeu mesmo!

Comment: Não o SO é chato para resposta , você precisa escrever um tese formato ABNT ... :) funfou deixa queito.